# How to save JMeter Aggregate Report results to a CSV file using command prompt?

Tags: csv, jmeter, command-prompt

I have been using JMeter in GUI mode for composing all the test cases required for load testing my service but for actual testing I need to execute tests in non-GUI mode.
How do I save the results of Aggregate report in csv file using command-prompt.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just as alternative: you may do this directly from the Aggregate Report listener.

**1.** set filename/template for results file:

```
resultsFile = ${__property(user.dir)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}result_${__time(yyyyMMdd-HHmmss)}.csv
```

**2.** configure Aggregate Report listener as shown below:

[image]

CSV-file generated in this case will differ from generated via GUI/"Save Table Data" one.


If it is not acceptable you'll better use method with JMeterPluginsCMD from previous answer:

```
java -jar JMeterPluginsCMD.jar --generate-csv aggregateResults.csv --input-jtl testResults.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

Comment: Your first answer (up to "If it is not acceptable...") does not make any sense - it is just writing tests results (like from _View Results Tree_) and have nothing in common with _Aggregate Report_ itself.

Comment: I used this command line tool but only got the following columns. 95%, 99% percentiles are missing.

sampler_label,aggregate_report_count,average,aggregate_report_median,aggregate_report_90%_line,aggregate_report_min,aggregate_report_max,aggregate_report_error%,aggregate_report_rate,aggregate_report_bandwidth,aggregate_report_stddev

Comment: @Makmeksam, you've got these columns in generated csv because they are predefined in plugin's source code. Looks like there is no configuration way to add percentiles or other sample params into csv (in contrast with Aggregate Report listener for which you can add 2nd and 3rd percentiles via user.properties file by setting additional properties: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report).

Comment: @Makmeksam, here you can fin in separate branch updated source code of JMPlugins 1.4.0 release which will add both 95th & 99th percentiles to generated AggregateReport csv: https://github.com/aliesbelik/jmeter-plugins/tree/aggregate-upd. Or diff only: https://github.com/aliesbelik/jmeter-plugins/commit/a257c85f2ec0f9a9ae3b1e98af0df1fcfbd9f575#diff-6f6c237d32fcfb66d51138fd9020a3bb. You have to rebuild project and replace JMeterPlugins-Standard.jar in JMETER_HOME/lib/ext/.

Answer (score 9):

Use [JMeterPluginsCMD](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) tool with Plugin Type = AggregateReport

Answer (score 6):

**1. Save result file**

Specify a result file to saved into in View Results Tree or View Table Results (in CSV or XML). Ex: `out/test-results.csv` or with CLI argument  `-JTEST_RESULTS_FILE=out/test-results.csv`

**2. Convert to report**

Convert the result file into an aggregate report:

```
$ java -jar CMDRunner.jar  --tool Reporter --generate-csv aggregateResults.csv --input-jtl out/test-results.csv --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

If you use `brew`, CMDRunner is located at:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/jmeter/2.13/libexec/lib/ext/CMDRunner.jar
```

Comment: BTW I ha to install an extra plugin because of what I read here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jmeter-plugins/Da4YN_nLvJA. BTW there is a cmd plugin runner in the jmeter bin folder to avoid calling the jar directly

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [JMeterPluginsCMD](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/).
2. Move jmeter-plugins-manager-0.13.jar into /bin/libs/ext of your JMeter.
3. Open JMeter, go to Options > Plugins Manager.
4. Install the following plug-ins:

   - Synthesis Report
   - Command line graph plotting tool
5. Run this command from your JMeter's /bin folder: 
   `./JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --tool Reporter --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl input.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport`

Comment: To use jmeter gui "Plugins Manager" downlaoding plugins will automate download then dependency plugin.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from the above answer, I wrote a simple bash script to automate the work of generating aggregated result `.csv` file using `.jtl` files

You can put this script in the folder where  `.jtl` files are in , and just run the script in that directory.
Then, it will put all the aggregated reports(`.csv` files) in the `aggregate_report` directory in the same directory

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

echo "Generating reports..."
command_runner="/opt/apache-jmeter-2.13/lib/ext/CMDRunner.jar"
output="aggregate_report"
count=0

mkdir $output

for sample_file in *.jtl
do
        ((count++))
        filename="${sample_file%.*}"
        echo "Converting $filename"
        java -jar $command_runner --tool Reporter --generate-csv ${output}/${filename}.csv --input-jtl ${filename}.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
done

echo "$count files were converted."
```

> note: change the `command_runner` variable accordingly with your **CMDRunner.jar** location