# Can i give multiple files in Jmeter command line to “save table data” in a aggregate report?

Tags: jmeter

My issue is similar to : [Jmeter command line to "save table data" in a aggregate report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618969/jmeter-command-line-to-save-table-data-in-a-aggregate-report)

Above solution worked for one input file i.e.

```
java -jar CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv"C:\Aggregate_Report.csv" --input-jtl "C:\output.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

But I run multiple instance of jmeter so I have 3 raw result .csv  files. I tried below:

```
java -jar CMDRunner.jar  --tool Reporter --generate-csv aggregateResults.csv --input-jtl file0.csv --input-jtl file1.csv --input-jtl file2.csv --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

But it is not working.

Using GUI mode I can merge 3 files into one aggregate file. Please suggest the correct command for linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

CMDRunner does not support multi-file generation either aggregated or sequentially.

What you want to do is merge these files first, then run it:

`cat file1.csv >> file0.csv
cat file2.csv >> file0.csv`

then

`java -jar CMDRunner.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv "file0.csv" --input-jtl "C:\output.jtl" --plugin-type AggregateReport`