# Automaticng "Save Table Data" from Summary Report/Aggregate Report of Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, listener, jmeter-4.0

I would like to know how to "Save Table Data" from Summary Report of JMeter automatically so that I can conclude on the Throughput rate.

Currently I can click over "Save Table Data" button at the bottom of the report and store it but how can I automate it.

Also, adding File name in browser saves the data but the header's are different as shown onscreen of Summary/Aggregate report.

P.S: I want to download/save the headers that are displayed on screen of Summary Report / Aggregate Report automatically

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Specific pages that you should read include [How Do I Ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please take these introductory steps and then edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the jmeter Non-GUI-Mode options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) `-e` and `-o`. The generated HTML [Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) contains a statistics table with this information.

However, further processing of the table data seems tricky, because it is hard-coded as JSON in the generated `<report_name>/content/js/dashboard.js` file.