# How to use CMDRunner to convert JTL file to Save table csv?

Tags: java, jmeter, maven-3, jmeter-plugins

In an answer here it is suggested to create a bat file to convert JTL file into CSV file which will have "save table data."

[Jmeter command line to "save table data" in a aggregate report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618969/jmeter-command-line-to-save-table-data-in-a-aggregate-report)

I have added `CMDRunner.jar` maven dependency in project's `pom.xml` file. Using this I want to write a piece of java code that would help me to do what bat file is doing above.

**I don't understand the functions given in this api/jar. How do I start?**

[image]

Later I would have maven life cycle which would run as follows:

1. mvn clean verify > Output will be jtl file
2. mvn test > JTL converted to CSV using piece of code from above
3. mvn sendreports > send csv to email

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to use JMeter Plugins API the easiest way would be going for [Maven Exec plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/), this way you will be able to execute [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) with necessary parameters in arbitrary phase of [Maven Build Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Example *pom.xml* file would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>jmeter-maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.example.jmeter-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmd:2.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:cmdrunner:2.2.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter:0.6</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-graphs-basic:2.0</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-synthesis:2.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-filterresults:2.1</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <downloadExtensionDependencies>false</downloadExtensionDependencies>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-cmdrunner-to-lib-folder</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <basedir>${basedir}/target/jmeter/lib/ext</basedir>
                            <executable>cp</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>cmdrunner-2.2.1.jar ..</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-aggregate-report</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <basedir>${basedir}/target/jmeter/lib</basedir>
                            <executable>java</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>-jar cmdrunner-2.2.1.jar --tool Reporter --generate-csv ${basedir}/target/aggregate.csv --input-jtl ${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/${timestamp}-test.csv --plugin-type AggregateReport</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It will produce `aggregate.csv` file in *target* folder which will contain textual representation of the [Aggregate Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) data

For non-Maven executions you can install the required plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)