# Jmeter Aggrgate Report data not saved in .csv file

Tags: jmeter

I configured a 'Jmeter Aggregate Report' against a Thread Group. And when I run the same in GUI mode - I can see the 'Aggregate report' table/**columns** in gui and it looks ok also.

But same report if I look in the saved statistics1.csv file it doesn't contains same **columns** data in .csv file, like all the required aggregate report table columns data are not in saved aggregate file (columns like, ***average, median, max, min, throughput*** etc).

[image: Jmeter Aggregate Report]

[image: CSV File]

**Could you please help me, how can I get 'Aggregate Table' data in CSV file?**

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to save it directly from the listener as the data is being **calculated** basing on the values from the .jtl results file.

If you need to generate the report in unattended manner you can use [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) which has `AggregateReport` plugin, this seems to be something you're looking for.

You can install the plugin (and keep it up-to-date) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Command Line Plotting Tool]

Comment: @Dimitri: Can you please tell me how to use this JmeterPluginsCMD. I followed all the steps mentioned in "https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/" but its throwing an error.

Command: JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl statistics1.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport

Error:  unable to access jar file

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [JMeterPluginsCMD](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/).
2. Move jmeter-plugins-manager-0.13.jar into /bin/libs/ext of your JMeter.
3. Open JMeter, go to Options > Plugins Manager.
4. Install the following plug-ins:

   - Synthesis Report
   - Command line graph plotting tool
5. Run this command from your JMeter's /bin folder: 
   `./JMeterPluginsCMD.sh --tool Reporter --generate-csv test.csv --input-jtl input.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45112998/4630195.